# Laravel-excel File not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-excel

I have a photo which is located under this link:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/391987500/2.jpg

I'm trying to include it in to excel file but I always have an error.

I try this:

```
<img src="/photos/{{$car->lot_id}}/2.jpg" width="30" height="30">
```

it returns this error:

> File /photos/391987500/2.jpg not found!

I try this:

```
<img src="{{ public_path() . '/photos/' . $car->lot_id . '/2.jpg'}}" width="200" height="200">
```

it returns this error:

> File /Users/apple/projects/asystem/public/photos/391991903/2.jpg not
>   found!

I try also this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/photos/' . $car->lot_id . '/2.jpg')}}" width="200" height="200">
```

and it also returns error:

> File http://127.0.0.1:8000/photos/391987500/2.jpg not found!

How can I get it done?

Comment: is photos directory inside public directory??

Comment: @MeeraTank yes photo is under public/photos/391987500/2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i get it! no need for`/` just need to do `<img src="photos/{{$car->lot_id}}/2.jpg" width="30" height="30">`

Sorry, my bad